Laragon. git is not recognized. How do I fix this? Also the 'clear' command is not running either
A screenshot of the issueI installed laragon and was setting up the environment in vscode. When I run the "php -v" command in the laragon terminal, it shows the php version just fine. But when I run the "git -v", it says ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.]
And when I try to clear the terminal screen with "clear" command, the same error message is displayed.
What can I do to solve this issue?

In the notification area on the taskbar, right click on laragon icon and select

tools > path > add laragon to path

after that restart laragon and open new cmd window
